# How do I rename a file?

Tags: c, linux, unix

How can I rename a file on unix platform programatically without using the standard rename function?

Comment: If you know how to, just answer the question instead of asking for the reason why..

Comment: check this link:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/search/label/rename

Answer (score 38):

The historical way to rename a file is to use link(2) to create a new hardlink to the same file, then to use unlink(2) to remove the old name.

Comment: That won't work on directories. There is good reason for having an atomic rename(2).

Answer (score 4):

The following is a somewhat ironic solution, that does not use the standard `rename(2)` system call by itself:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

if (system("mv file1 file2") != 0)
    perror("system");
```

It's an indirect usage of `rename(2)`, this syscall is invoked by `mv(1)`.

Comment: Don't forget that 'mv' does considerably more than 'rename()' when the source and target locations are on different file systems.